# Missing return statement inside switch

Tags: java

i have a method which returns a boolean value . Ive added return statement in every case of my switch statements and added default which also returns a value but still im getting the "Missing return statement" . 
Whats missing ?

```
private boolean isDateValid ()
{  
    if ((_day>31) || (_day<=0))                     
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((_month>12) || (_month<=0))  
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((_year>9999) || (_year<1000))
    {
        return true;
    }
    switch (_month)
    {
        case 1:
            if (_day>JANUARY)
                return true;   
            break;
        case 2:
            if ((_year % 400 == 0) || ((_year % 4 == 0) && (_year % 100 != 0)))
            {
            if (_day>FEBRUARY_LEAP)
                return true;
            }
            else if (_day>FEBRUARY)
                return true;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (_day>MARCH)
                return true;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (_day>APRIL)
                return true;
            break;
        case 5:
            if (_day>MAY)
                return true;
            break;  
        case 6:
            if (_day>JUNE)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 7:
            if (_day>JULY)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 8:
            if (_day>AUGUST)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 9:
            if (_day>SEPTEMBER)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 10:
            if (_day>OCTOBER)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 11:
            if (_day>NOVEMBER)
                return true;
            break;    
        case 12:
            if (_day>DECEMBER)
                return true;
            break; 
        default: return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Just to let you know, if you `return` from a switch case you don't need to worry about `break`ing as well.

Comment: Why do all of you case statements have `break;`? **Hint** they don't need `break` if the `return` is going to be reached.

Comment: outside of everything. If all the IFs don't go and switch doesn't go. compiler isn't going inside statements to understand that you'll have return statement in every situation

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys , in this case most of the time they dont enter the if statement .

Comment: Just a note - this method  seems to return true if the date is invalid, and false if it's valid.  Perhaps `isDateValid` is not the best name for such a method.

Comment: True , i will rename it . Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this case :

```
case 3:
    if (_day>MARCH)
        return true;
    break;
```

You only return a value if the condition is true.

Instead, write

```
case 3:
    return _day>MARCH;
```

This will return true if the condition is met and false otherwise.

The same applies to all you case clauses.

Comment: Shainke, it would be polite of you to accept this answer on Stackoverflow. I'm sure that Eran would appreciate it and it makes it more clear to others that this is the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using **if** in your **case statement**( if that if expression doesn't match method will not have any return value )

case 3:
            if (_day>MARCH)
                return true;
            break;

Answer (score 0):

```
Add `return false;` above the last bracket `}` and replace each `break;` statement 

private boolean isDateValid ()
{  
    if ((_day>31) || (_day<=0))                     
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((_month>12) || (_month<=0))  
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((_year>9999) || (_year<1000))
    {
        return true;
    }
    switch (_month)
    {
        case 1:
            if (_day>JANUARY)
                return true;   
return false;

        case 2:
            if ((_year % 400 == 0) || ((_year % 4 == 0) && (_year % 100 != 0)))
            {
            if (_day>FEBRUARY_LEAP)
                return true;
            }
            else if (_day>FEBRUARY)
                return true;
return false;

        case 3:
            if (_day>MARCH)
                return true;
return false;

        case 4:
            if (_day>APRIL)
                return true;
return false;

        case 5:
            if (_day>MAY)
                return true;
return false;

        case 6:
            if (_day>JUNE)
                return true;
return false;

        case 7:
            if (_day>JULY)
                return true;
return false;

        case 8:
            if (_day>AUGUST)
                return true;
return false;

        case 9:
            if (_day>SEPTEMBER)
                return true;
return false;

        case 10:
            if (_day>OCTOBER)
                return true;
return false;

        case 11:
            if (_day>NOVEMBER)
                return true;
return false;

        case 12:
            if (_day>DECEMBER)
                return true;
return false;

        default: return false;
            }
return false;
    }
```

Comment: Oh , now i see what i was missing . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isDateValid ()
{  

    boolean flag = false;

    if ((_day>31) || (_day12) || (_month9999) || (_yearJANUARY)
                flag = true;   
            break;
        case 2:
            if ((_year % 400 == 0) || ((_year % 4 == 0) && (_year % 100 != 0)))
            {
            if (_day>FEBRUARY_LEAP)
                flag = true;
            }
            else if (_day>FEBRUARY)
                flag = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (_day>MARCH)
                flag = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (_day>APRIL)
                flag = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            if (_day>MAY)
                flag = true;
            break;  
        case 6:
            if (_day>JUNE)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 7:
            if (_day>JULY)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 8:
            if (_day>AUGUST)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 9:
            if (_day>SEPTEMBER)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 10:
            if (_day>OCTOBER)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 11:
            if (_day>NOVEMBER)
                flag = true;
            break;    
        case 12:
            if (_day>DECEMBER)
                flag = true;
            break; 
        default: return flag;
            }

     return flag;
    }
```